# Make UISlider height larger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uislider

I've been searching for a way to make the `UISlider` progress bar taller, like increasing the height of the slider but couldn't find anything. I don't want to use a custom image or anything, just make it taller, so the `UISlider` doesn't look so thin. Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe you could try by changing the scale factor ? Not sure it would work as intended.

Comment: Would you exemplify what you mean? The scale factor of what?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. The following method just needs to be edited in a subclass.

```
override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
   var customBounds = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
   customBounds.size.height = ...
   return customBounds
}
```

Comment: This is good (and works), but don't forget to call bounds = [super trackRectForBounds:bounds]; or else it will change the slider frame..

Comment: @Cutetare, Why would you need to call the super `trackRectForBounds:` method if you want to pass your own bounds?

Answer (score 69):

The accepted answer will undesirably change the slider's width in some cases, like if you're using a `minimumValueImage` and `maximumValueImage`.  If you only want to change the height and leave everything else alone, then use this code:

```
override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
   var newBounds = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
   newBounds.size.height = 12
   return newBounds
}
```

Comment: Just as an extra step, you can add `newBounds.origin.y -= 6` (or your new value divided by 2) just to be sure it's centered in Y with the new thickness value.

Comment: @FernandoMata not quite 6... need to subtract `(newHeight-originalHeight)/2` from `y`

Answer (score 38):

Here's my recent swifty implementation, building on CularBytes's ...

```
open class CustomSlider : UISlider {
    @IBInspectable open var trackWidth:CGFloat = 2 {
        didSet {setNeedsDisplay()}
    }

    override open func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let defaultBounds = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return CGRect(
            x: defaultBounds.origin.x,
            y: defaultBounds.origin.y + defaultBounds.size.height/2 - trackWidth/2,
            width: defaultBounds.size.width,
            height: trackWidth
        )
    }
}
```

Use this on a UISlider in a storyboard by setting its custom class
[image: Custom class setting]

The IBInspectable allows you to set the height from the storyboard
[image: Height from storyboard]

Comment: The `@IBInspectable` is an _amazing_ addition 

Comment: Thanx bro for this.

Answer (score 20):

For those that would like to see some working code for changing the track size.

```
class CustomUISlider : UISlider {

    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        //keeps original origin and width, changes height, you get the idea
        let customBounds = CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSize(width: bounds.size.width, height: 5.0))
        super.trackRect(forBounds: customBounds)
        return customBounds
    }

    //while we are here, why not change the image here as well? (bonus material)
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "customThumb"), for: .normal)
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Only thing left is changing the class inside the storyboard:

[image: storyboardstuff]

You can keep using your seekbar action and outlet to the object type UISlider, unless you want to add some more custom stuff to your slider.

Comment: Meh. This works but it messes the alignment of the `UISlider` up quite a bit and the `setThumbImage` function doesn't work.

Comment: Please elaborate why it messes the alignment up? Are you sure setThumbImage doesn't work? I've just checked in Xcode  7.0 beta, Swift 2.0

Comment: I think the origin isn't centering it vertically (like the default UISlider). I just added a top constraint to counter it.

Comment: @BrightFuture Are you sure `forBounds bounds` is swift 3? Is the complete code working on swift 3? I'm not currently into swift 3 development but just want to verify, looks odd.

Comment: @CularBytes yes it does, the code is converted by Xcode

Answer (score -2):

You could play with this, see what happens:

```
slider.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 2.0);
```

Comment: Because this changes the whole frame instead of just the bar like the question stated and doesn't re-adjust the corner radius or the thumb slider frames so everything looks disproportionate.