# UISlider track not increasing in thickness

Tags: swift, uislider

I can't seem to increase the thickness of the track. Been trying other recommendations and looking for this option in the documentation but it doesn't seem to be working, anyone know why?:(

```
class factionButton: UISlider {
var factionSlider = UISlider() 

func factionBalanceSlider(){
    factionSlider.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 542, width: 386, height: 57)
    factionSlider.minimumValueImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Alliance Slider")
    factionSlider.maximumValueImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Horde Slider")
    factionSlider.setThumbImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Thumb Image"), for: .normal)
    factionSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.33, blue:0.69, alpha:0.8)
    factionSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.59)

    factionSlider.setValue(0.5, animated: true)
    factionSlider.isContinuous = true
    factionSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(recordFactionBalance(sender:)) , for: .valueChanged)
}

func getSlider() -> UISlider {
    return factionSlider
}

override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let customBounds = CGRect(x: 16, y: 21, width: 343, height: 7)
    super.trackRect(forBounds: customBounds)
    return customBounds
}
```

Comment: I Think Thickness here you mean by Height ?

Comment: @iOSGeek Yeah, that

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/35820464/6080920 You are providing height just 7 its too small

Comment: @iOSGeek I was meaning to find that again after I lost it. Thanks! I put in 7, and then 700 but it doesn't seem to be changing the track size at all:(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in many other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590188/how-to-customise-uislider-height), you can change the height by creating a custom slider as below,

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {

    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        rect.size.height = 7
        return rect
    }
}
```

But in your particular case, you are not seeing the change because your implementation is not allowing the `factionSlider` to use `overridden` `trackRect`. To use that you need to change that to `CustomSlider` as below,

```
class FactionButton: UISlider {
    var factionSlider = CustomSlider() 

    func factionBalanceSlider(){
        factionSlider.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 542, width: 386, height: 57)
        factionSlider.minimumValueImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Alliance Slider")
        factionSlider.maximumValueImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Horde Slider")
        factionSlider.setThumbImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Thumb Image"), for: .normal)
        factionSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.33, blue:0.69, alpha:0.8)
        factionSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.59)

        factionSlider.setValue(0.5, animated: true)
        factionSlider.isContinuous = true
        factionSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(recordFactionBalance(sender:)) , for: .valueChanged)
    }

    func getSlider() -> UISlider {
        return factionSlider
    }
}
```

**Note** In `Swift`, `class` name should start with Capital as i updated above. Secondly, I think `FactionButton` should not be a `subclass` of `UISlider`.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you! I can't believe I missed this. Time to go to sleep. Thanks you:3

Comment: Solved all my problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should get the current bounds from the super class first, then just change the height:

```
override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var customBounds = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
    customBounds.size.height = 7
    return customBounds
}
```

Comment: I was going to figure out how to do this, thanks! But the track seems to still stay the same as before I overrode it:(

Comment: make sure you are using your UISlider class `factionButton` for the `Custom Class` Attribute in your storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the rect size expands the slider to the bottom only. So the origin should be recalculated to keep the slider centered.

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomSlider: UISlider {

@IBInspectable var trackHeight: CGFloat = 6

override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var rect = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
    rect.size.height = trackHeight
    rect.origin.y -= trackHeight / 2
    return rect
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I made this by adding this

1.

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {
    
    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let point = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.midY)
        return CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: 10)) //this height is the thickness 
    }
    
}
```

2. storyboard - change UISlider class to my CustomSlider

[image]

FYI for newbie like me..
change color is here :)

[image]